# :first-child isn't working when targeting element using a descendant selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

For some reason, I am not able to select the first occurrence of an img element inside a div with the class `productdescription`.

Is this because the `img` is also within a p every time? The `img` has to be nested within a `p` every time, unfortunately, thanks to WordPress.

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div class="productdescription"><h3>Product Description</h3>
    <p>
        <img class="alignleft" src="#">
    </p>
    <p>Text here.</p>
    <p>
        <a href="#">
            <img class="alignleft" src="#">
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <img class="alignleft" src="#">
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <img class="alignleft" src="#">
    </p>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
 .productdescription img {
        float:left;
        width:30%;
        height:auto;
        margin:10px 20px 20px 0px;
 }

.productdescription img:first-child  {
    width:45%;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**The Problem:**

Using a descendent selector here will cause your CSS style to target the `img:first-child` **of each descendant element**.

For example, if you have the following markup:

```
<div class="productdescription">
   <p>
     <img class="alignleft" src="#" class="targetsMe"> <!-- This is selected -->
   </p>
   <p>
     <a href="#">
       <img class="alignleft" src="#" class="targetsMe"> <!-- So is this -->
     </a>
     <a href="#">
       <img class="alignleft" src="#" class="targetsMe"> <!-- And this -->
       <img class="alignleft" src="#"> <!-- But not this -->
     </a>
   </p>
</div>
```

Your current selector, `.productdescription img:first-child`, will target every `img` I have denoted with the class `targetsMe`.

[**Here's the jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tEg8W/3/) showing that.

---

**The Solution:**

In your case, as the image you want to target is always the only direct decsendant of a `p` element, you could select it is like so: `.productdescription p > img:first-child`

[**jsFiddle example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tEg8W/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.productdescription h3+p img
{
Your styles here
}
```

Yes, all your img tags are the first-child of the parent tag (p in some cases, a in others).  So what you have should select all the img tags.  This will select only the img within a p tag that is preceeded by an h3 within .productdescription

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are selecting all the *img*'s, right?

If you want to select only the first one you can't use `.productdescription img:first-child`, since that way you are selecting all the *img*'s that are the first element of it's parent —no matter who is that parent.

To select only the first image you might use `.productdescription p > img`, since the other images are wrapped with *a* elements. Or `.productdescription h3+p img`, since this way you select only the *p* element following an *h3* element.